# can not fire CK editor on second or third dropped dynamic element - CkEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I checked all the solutions online but can't fix it.

I am working on a kind of CMS where I drag and drop HTML widgets into the DOM and I need to apply CK Editor to the dynamically generated elements but I'm facing some issues here.

Here's the code which fires when a widget is dropped:

```
  //Triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped on the droppable
            drop: function (event, ui) {

//dropable Template here is complete HTML content
 var DropableTemplate = ui.draggable.attr("data-template");

//appending to event target
$(event.target).after(DropableTemplate);

// getting the editable [p] content from it
  var elementforCkEditor = $(event.target).find('p');

//I found this solution online 

                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < elementforCkEditor.length; i++) {
                    CKEDITOR.inline(elementforCkEditor .get(i))
                    delete CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
                }
```

It works Okay for the first time, but when I drop a second dynamic element, It doesn't fire CK editor on that.

**it shows the editor a little far from the actual element, in this case, a paragraph**

is this the right solution for this particular case? if yes how can I fix that?

I tried .replace, .editable but they don't happen to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elementforCkEditor.get(0)
```

In the above statement, you get the first element of the JQuery selection.

**Few things to focus on**

CKEditor expects the editable element to contain the attribute `contenteditable=true`

Also, there are permitted number of elements to be editable via CKEditor.

Please see [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dtd.html#property-S-editable) for those.

[This](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) is a very good source you can learn particularly about your case.

Note that you can pass the element id too to the CKEditor.

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'my-id', {
    startupFocus: true
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help there, I figured things out and happened to make it work but there's a space between the editable content and the CK Editor. like, please see the screenshot attached:

https://i.imgur.com/Qnb1jsW.png

they appear as two disconnected objects but it works fine on the preloaded objects, dynamic ones have space b/w the editor

Comment: The easiest way is to select the CKEditor instance element and change its position via css.